# Sum of all dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, column-sum

Here is what I need to find,

**Sum all values present in dynamically generated system columns.**

I have found how to generate dynamically generated columns by using following query.

```
    declare @columnnames nvarchar(max) =  'select COLUMN_NAME FROM  [Powerbireports].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = ''FCL_Pivot'' and column_name like ''%Charges'''
```

It shows the columns ending with charges.

I have 30+ columns of charges. 
My data looks like below.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9WOB.png)

**By using  this columns I need to perform sum of all values present in 30 columns(using above query) and update into another column named handling.**

I tried by using below query.

```
    declare @dynamicsql nvarchar(max) = N'Update [dbo].[FCL_Pivot] set Handling = (select SUM('+@columnnames+'))'
    exec sp_executesql @dynamicsql
```

It is showing incorrect syntax near 'select'.

Please help me how to overcome this query or any alternative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, build a comma-delimited list of all columns ending with 'charges':

```
DECLARE @column_plus_str NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @column_plus_str = STUFF((SELECT '+ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+ ', 0)'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FCL_Pivot' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%charges'
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Then update Handling. You don't need the SUM aggregate because you aren't grouping, right? Handling = ISNULL([100% Examination Charges], 0)+ISNULL([50% Examination Charges], 0) + ...

```
DECLARE @dynamicsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Update [dbo].[FCL_Pivot] set Handling = ' + @column_plus_str
EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicsql
```